# Pedestrian unreachable target

Tags: anylogic

I am attempting a simulation in AnyLogic and I am not very experienced. I am getting errors saying that the location that the pedscource is assigned to goto is inaccessible despite being very much accessible. I'm sure this is something elementary that I had messed up but as I said, I am very new to this software.

Console out:

`Exception during discrete event execution: root.pedGoTo.pedGoToTarget: Unreachable target: (1925.64, 1600.00) on level 'name: level' for pedestrian 'id: 1' located at: (1550.00, 830.31) on level 'name: level'! java.lang.RuntimeException: root.pedGoTo.pedGoToTarget: Unreachable target: (1925.64, 1600.00) on level 'name: level' for pedestrian 'id: 1' located at: (1550.00, 830.31) on level 'name: level'! at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source) at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)`

I have tried remaking the pedsource and goto blocks, I have tried remaking the target lines. I have tried deleting other levels. (I know its not much but there is not much to troubleshoot because the only things in this model is walls.)

Answer (score 1):

what usually is the reason for this problem, even though it might not solve yours, is that you might have a wall too close to a node, or a wall inside a node... make sure any wall is at least the diameter of the pedestrian far from any wall.

Something else that is very annoying is that sometimes when the pedestrian is moving, the momemntum of the movement makes the pedestrian to locate himself inside a wall for a short period of time, if you request a new destination for that pedestrian at that point in time, it will say it's not possible.

Another reason is that you might send the agent to a corner that is smaller than the size of the pedestrian... make sure your destinations are at least as far as at least the diameter of the pedestrian from any nearby wall.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, sometimes happens, especially if there are small openings that seemingly look like peds could pass but the algorithm does not "see" them.

Best bet is to work iteratively (ALWAYS):

1. add a tiny bit of functionality (ped walks from A to B)
2. test the hell out of it
3. repeat step 1

This way, you always know which tiny change caused a problem and you can rectify.

This is true for all modelling, tbh